# C++ SFML 2.1 undefined reference to GLEW

Tags: c++, linux, sfml, glew

I am trying to compile this:

```
#include < SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

clang ++ -c main.cpp  works!!

clang++ main.o -o sfml-app -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

gives me fallowing error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libGLEW.so.1.5, needed by /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libjpeg.so.62, needed by /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_finish_compress@LIBJPEG_6.2'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_write_scanlines@LIBJPEG_6.2'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__glewUniform1fARB'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_std_error@LIBJPEG_6.2'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__GLEW_ARB_shader_objects'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__glewGetObjectParameterivARB'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__GLEW_ARB_vertex_shader'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__glewFramebufferTexture2DEXT'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__glewUniformMatrix4fvARB'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_set_quality@LIBJPEG_6.2'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__glewGenFramebuffersEXT'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__glewUniform3fARB'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_set_defaults@LIBJPEG_6.2'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__glewRenderbufferStorageEXT'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateCompress@LIBJPEG_6.2'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__GLEW_ARB_fragment_shader'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__glewActiveTextureARB'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_start_compress@LIBJPEG_6.2'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__glewShaderSourceARB'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `glewInit'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__glewBindFramebufferEXT'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__glewFramebufferRenderbufferEXT'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__glewLinkProgramARB'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__glewUseProgramObjectARB'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__glewBlendFuncSeparateEXT'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__glewGenRenderbuffersEXT'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__glewUniform2fARB'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy_compress@LIBJPEG_6.2'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__glewUniform4fARB'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__glewCreateProgramObjectARB'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `glewGetErrorString'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__glewCompileShaderARB'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__glewDeleteRenderbuffersEXT'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__glewDeleteObjectARB'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__glewGetUniformLocationARB'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__glewGetInfoLogARB'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__GLEW_EXT_blend_func_separate'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__glewDeleteFramebuffersEXT'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__glewCheckFramebufferStatusEXT'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__glewUniform1iARB'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__GLEW_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_stdio_dest@LIBJPEG_6.2'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__GLEW_ARB_shading_language_100'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__glewCreateShaderObjectARB'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__glewBindRenderbufferEXT'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__GLEW_EXT_framebuffer_object'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__glewAttachObjectARB'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__glewGetHandleARB'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error messages in the first two lines tell you are apparently missing `libGLEW` and `libjpeg`. You need to install the development packages of each of them (or download, compile, and install them yourself).

The other errors are just the missing functions that are expected to be in either of the dependency libs.

Comment: Thank you for response, I downloaded it from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/glew/files/glew/1.11.0/        i fallowed readme on how to install but i gained nothnig. I know its probably dumb qustions but am new to this, sorry

Comment: @Edin: from the error message, I'd say you need version 1.5 of GLEW and  version 62 of libjpeg. otherwise the shared objects cannot be found. (you could tinker with the symbolic links though). But as I said, usually the libraries come packaged by the OS packaging system, which is the preferred way to go.